# Where should i start for a perfect degradable good to use websites

Tags: javascript, html

In the current web development world with mobile devices kicking in, Browser wars still a pain and more UI attractiveness, how should one `actually` start designing & programming websites. Should

#### Question

- First develop site to support javascript & UI goodness turned off then
- slowly add effects and enhancements? or

it just plain matter of taste.

#### Opinion

Have you used any techniques, how has it helped

(this isn't the question actually, so don't close the post thinking this is question. I want opinions to this with answers to above question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keep graceful degradation in mind. It's pretty hard making a *good* experience these days by making a basic HTML & CSS layout and then coating it with some javascript effects.

Have a clear idea of what exactly you're going to be accomplishing with the site. When developing, remember to separate content and presentation. Generate your HTML. Add the CSS to make it look good. Build extra functionality with javascript, while keeping in mind that the extra functionality should work even without JS if it's being used to content delivery.

For example, when using ajax to load up dynamic content, you would first add an anchor tag with a link to an actual page that has the data. Then, include JS that if running, would hijack the click, load up the data in the background and display the relevant content dynamically.

Simply adhering to the guidelines that a) Your markup should be semantic b) your immediate content should make sense with JS and CSS turned off and that c) not having javascript should not adversely affect the usefulness of your site will help tremendously.

A lot of people recently started talking about responsive design as well. This will help your site not look like crap when loaded up on different sized screens.

Of course, most of it comes down to your target user base too. If you're say, building a utility for web developers, you can assume they have the newest baddest browsers, and go to town with all the JS you want. On the other hand, if you're making say, a website for a local pre-school, your audience might not have the browsers needed to make more intensive javascript work.

It all boils down to judging the situation correctly, and making an informed decision on just how much you can depend on technology that is not plain HTML to deliver a good experience.

Comment: answered well enough to be voted as answer

Answer (score 1):

- first you create a checklist that which UI goodness you need to develop your website.
- then search for best JavaScript library which is best fit for your website and apply it along with designs otherwise there may be many issue like 
  `Browser compatibility`,`CSS conflicts`,`Javascript library conflicts`
  and you will stuck in middle.

because sometimes you did some basic functionality with **core javascript**, but later you use some javascript library and then realise that the functionaly u develope by core javascript ,can be done very easily using these libraries.

I prefer **[jQuery](http://jquery.com/)**, bcoz there is very well documentation on the web.

hope it helps you.
Thanks

Comment: +1 for create a checklist and do your homework

Answer (score 1):

Hm. Interesting enough question. Here is what I think...Two answers:

- some sites only exist because of the growing tech possibilites. Certain data, content and information cannot be viewed without it, or at least not meaningfully. To describe a map is tedious and pointless, to display one in one form solves fifty problems in one image. Imagine having to write directions to your house from five directions, as a bulletlist. Rather than just stick a map in there.

This however is in minority, a lot of sites have added coolness that the content does not technically need. So. I think that things should be kept as simple as possible, *really* as simple as possible.

But not one bit simpler.

But I am *not* Jacob Nielsen. I think at least in the abstract development phase, you should not rely on - or consider - "bling", animations, menue effects etc. The architectural structure must be on a sound basis first. To "fix" information architecture with UI effects is common but awful. Of course, the lack of real estate might push you in a direction of nifty, animated ajax solutions. No problem with that.

As there is a big difference between an efficient system architecture - backend - and the frontend structure, you cannot repair rubbish groundwork in the backend with bling in the front. Well. You can. But I see it and want to scream ;-) Or if you use your frontend to mimic your backend. Urrgh.

So in short, I think content comes first. Some content benefit and need js & UI goodies to be presented meaningfully, but I think the *process* should focus on basic structures. When that is solid and nicely done, you can carefully add "fun" stuff. There is always a danger of the "pretty-fying" overriding the use, the UI and the content.

Comment: +1 for To "fix" information architecture with UI effects is common but awful.

Comment: :-) thanks - I thought it was a more abstract question, so fair enough.